# Automatic width for display of FlowDocument

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

In my application, I'm generating a FlowDocument with several paragraphs of text.

Using a [FlowDocumentScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentscrollviewer.aspx) , I can display the document in my UI. If the document is too long for the available space, the FlowDocumentScrollViewer does it's job and introduces a vertical scrollbar. All good.

If I use a [FlowDocumentPageViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentpageviewer.aspx) the response to show additional pages of text, also as designed.

However, what I want in my application is for the viewer to grow wider.

So, for a short document, the viewer is narrow (say, around 360 pixels with one column of text), but for a longer document the viewer is wider (say, around 720 pixels with two columns of text). An even longer document would expand to three columns, and so on.

I've seen a number of WinRT applications that do this kind of thing - [The New Zealand Herald](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/en-gb/app/the-new-zealand-herald/5bf5ecca-30d3-4fc9-8542-e0ded824b94d) has one app. But, I'm working in regular WPF and have ended up stumped.

**How can I display a FlowDocument so that it's all visible at once - no scrollbars, no pagination, just multiple columns of text stretching across?**

Why do I want this? I'm showing several disparate pieces of information on a single page, and I want to have a single horizontal scrollbar for panning across the lot, not separate scrollbars for each piece. For example, I've got my ListBoxes working this way by using a WrapPanel as the ItemsPanelTemplate - when there are too many items for one column, another column opens up and the listbox gets wider to accomodate.